# Exeption: "attribute 'remove' is not allowed." in developer mode

Tags: magento2.3.3, category-view, porto-theme

When i enable the developer mode on my Magento 2.3.3 instance i get the following error message when calling category pages in webbrowser:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
Line: 976

Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
Line: 980


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
Line: 976

Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
Line: 980

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:494]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:470]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php:193]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:587]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getElementAttribute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:545]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->addBodyClass() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Category/View.php:217]
#15 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#16 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#17 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php:26]
#19 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#21 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#22 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#23 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php:39]
#24 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#29 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]
#31 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
</pre>
```

Im using a child theme based on the porto theme. My `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` looks as follows:

```xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
             <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_banner" template="category/banner.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/category/category_description" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="category_overview" template="Magento_Catalog::category/view.phtml"/> -->
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_desc_main_column" template="category/desc_main_column.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/category/category_description" before="category.products" remove="1"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="1"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main" remove="1">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="category_view_custom_block" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::category/custom_block.phtml" remove="1"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    <move element="category.view.container" destination="content"  after="-"/>
</page>
```

How can I get rid of the error messages, what have I missed?

Comment: Your remove block syntax is wrong click here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306602/exeption-attribute-remove-is-not-allowed-in-developer-mode/306621#306621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I had to replace the old syntax `remove="1"` against the modern one: `remove="true"`.

I also removed the other `remove="1"` attributes out of my first post from the block elements and replaced them with a single statement:

```xml
<referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true" />
```

@BartZalas has been a big help and pointed me to the appropriate place in the Magento 2.3.x documentation: [Common layout customization tasks, Rearrange elements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange)

My `catalog_category_view.xml` file now works as expected and looks like this:

```xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="page.top">
                 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_banner" template="category/banner.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/category/category_description" before="-"/>
            </referenceContainer>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <!-- <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="category_overview" template="Magento_Catalog::category/view.phtml"/> -->
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_desc_main_column" template="category/desc_main_column.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/category/category_description" before="category.products" />
            </referenceContainer>
            <referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true" />
            <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
                <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="category_view_custom_block" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::category/custom_block.phtml" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
        <move element="category.view.container" destination="content"  after="-"/>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you found this remove="1" ???

Should be

remove="true"

Like:

`<referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>`

Reference:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange

Comment: `remove="1"` were the default values in the vendor file catalog_category_view.xml of the installed Porto Theme.

I think the problems are caused by these lines in the catalog_category_view.xml:
`<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_desc_main_column" template="category/desc_main_column.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/category/category_description" before="category.products" remove="1"/>` and `<block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="category_view_custom_block" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::category/custom_block.phtml" remove="1"/>`

Comment: so just remove remove="1" from referenceBlock parts like its says in the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the mistake:
For some reason the catalog_product_view.xml of my child theme ([...]/Smartwave/**porto_child**/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml) is not loaded.

Instead, the file is loaded from the parent theme at [...]/Smartwave/**porto**/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml. I had not made any changes there yet

Answer (score 1):

```
Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed.
```

So **Block** tag not allow **remove** attribute.

If you want to remove follow this

```
<referenceBlock name=”block_name” remove=”true”/>
```

Source link [click here](https://magento2tutorial.magestore.com/remove-block-layout-magento-2/)

***I Hope This Helps You.***